# T-test for model selection

Tags: t-test, p-value, model-selection

How to use t-test for comparing two different models (or same model with different feature input)?
EXPLANATION: I have a Logistic Regression model with huge amount of parameters. I want to compare it with LR, but on smaller set of parameters USING t-tests. I am not looking for another solutions, cause I want to understand is it possible and to find background of this statistical approach.

Comment: (-1) This question is so lacking detail it is unanswerable. What are these models for? What types of models are you entertaining? Is a t test even appropriate, is it correct to fixate on that?

Comment: Could you elaborate? What are these "two different models"? How do you think a t-test would be appropriate? What are some concrete examples that would help people better understand what you are asking?

Comment: Probably not at all?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I give a summary how it is done, it is important to note that, since it does not fulfill one of the assumptions of the t-test (namely, all samples are iid), it has a hight Type I error (null hypothesis rejected when it is in fact true, that is, "often" you think that both classifiers have significantly different performance when they don't).

Say you want to compare two classifiers A and B. Let us denote by $h_{A}(T)$ and $h_{B}(T)$ the result of training those classifiers on the set $T$.

1. You divide your data, $D$, in into k disjoint subsets $T_{i}, i=1,...,k$, of equal size, where its size its at least 30.
2. For $i$ from 1 to $k$ do: train your classifiers on the set $D \setminus T_{i}$, and use $T_{i}$ for test. Calculate,
   $$
   \delta_{i} = error_{T_{i}}(h_{A}) - error_{T_{i}}(h_{B})
   $$
   the difference between the number of incorrectly classified samples on the test set by each of the classifiers, concretely, $error_{T_{i}}(h_{A})$ is the quotient between the number of errors and the number of samples in the test set.
3. Calculate the mean error:
   $$
   \bar{\delta} = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i} \delta_{i}
   $$
   The t-statistic is,
   $$
   t = \frac{\bar{\delta} \sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i}(\bar{\delta}-\delta_{i})^{2}}{k-1}}}
   $$

There are other approaches worth considering. See for example, [On Comparing Classifiers: Pitfalls to Avoid and a Recommended Approach](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~tomh/onderwijs/lrs/lrs_files/salzberg97comparing.pdf)

Comment: Good answer just one thing is unclear: is error(h) an absolute error? The interpretation of $t$ will differ if it is not

Comment: It is the sample error, that is, #errors/#samples.

Comment: Is it similar to Cross Validation, but on some sort of "two models"? After I get a t - I should compare it with a value in table?

Comment: yes, you then compare it with the corresponding value in the table, in order to see if the difference in the error rate between the two classifiers is significant enough.